# what's the best way to change an object property in a javascript object array?

Tags: javascript, performance

are there fastest/better performing ways to search and change a property of a javascript array of objects?

```
var myObjArr = [{'item' : 'one' , 'myProp' : 'propOne' }, 
                {'item' : 'two' , 'myProp' : 'propTwo' }];

for (var i = 0; i < myObjArr.length; i++) { 

    var myObj = myObjArr[i]; 

    for(prop in myObj){ 

        if(prop === 'item' && myObj[prop] == 'two'){

            myObj.myProp = 'propTwoEdited';

        }

   }        

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//forEach is faster
myObjArr.forEach(function(obj) {

    //just test the item prop value equals 'two' or not
    if (obj.item == 'two') {

        //obj is object, and a reference
        obj.myProp = 'propTwoEdited';
    }
});
```